# A for() loop to overwrite existing data.frames

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I'm testing some operations with that classical 99' Czech Bank data set, trying to execute a `tidyverse` task upon several data.frames in my global environment, but the loop I've created keeps overwriting the same object `val`, which was supposed to be a dummy for the df themselves:

```
x <- c("loans93","loans94","loans95","loans96",
       "loans97","loans98")
x <- base::mget(x, envir=as.environment(-1), mode= "any", inherits=F)

for (val in x) {
  val <- val %>%
    select(account_id, district_id, balance, status, date) %>% 
    group_by(account_id, district_id, status, date) %>%
    summarise(balance=mean(balance, na.rm=T)) %>%
    ungroup()
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I've searched for similar questions but people keep answering lapply solutions, I just need the task to be saved upon my DFs instead of this "val" object I keep getting.

Comment: is `x` supposed to be a list of dataframes?

Comment: yes, I've created a list of my data.frames in the ```x```

Comment: the output of the loop is performed correctly, but not saved in the distinct objects I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this:

```
df_names <- c("loans93", "loans94", "loans95",
              "loans96", "loans97", "loans98")

for(df_name in df_names){
    get(df_name) %>%
        head %>% ## replace with desired manipulations
        assign(value = .,
               x = paste0(df_name,'_manipulated'), ## or just: df_name to overwrite original
               envir = globalenv())
}
```

aside: `list2env` is handy to "spawn" list members (e. g. dataframes) into the environment. Example:

```
list_of_dataframes <- list(
    iris_short = head(iris),
    cars_short = head(cars)
)

list2env(x = list_of_dataframes)
```

Comment: Yessss!! It worked perfectly, I'll do your laundry for the rest of the year, thank you!!